# Cannot open samba ports on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I'm newbie to linux firewalls

```
root@Ubntu:~# ufw status verbose
state: active
logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
new profiles: skip
137,138/udp (Samba)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
139,445/tcp (Samba)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
137,138/udp (Samba (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
139,445/tcp (Samba (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

ufw allow samba (or http) - does nothing, port stays closed
ufw allow ssh - opens ssh port
ufw disable - only ssh port is open

according netstat samba server is listening on:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:139           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:445           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I assume that some other firewall rules forbid access.

Please help troubleshoot the problem

PS tried to clear iptables firewall rules with no luck:
    iptables -F
    iptables -X
    iptables -t nat -F
    iptables -t nat -X
    iptables -t mangle -F
    iptables -t mangle -X
    iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your samba server is listening only to localhost interface. You need to have the following in your `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
    interfaces = eth0
    bind interfaces only = yes
```

This way Samba will listen to `eth0` interface, so that connections coming from the network are accepted.